# (Vue.js) The icon does not apply

Tags: html, vue.js, icons, favicon

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="./icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./icons/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./icons/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="./icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg">
```

I added this code.
But the icon does not apply.

The file structure is
**test

　└icons

　　└safari-pinned-tab.svg

　　└favicon-16x16.png

　　└favicon-32x32.png

　　└apple-touch-icon.png

　└index.html**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="icons/apple-touch-icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="icons/apple-touch-icon.png">


  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- DO NOT touch the -->
  </body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: The icon works normally when only the '.html' file is opened. But this does not apply if ‘npm run dev’ is used.

Comment: I solved the problem by moving the image path to /static/